# Insertar fecha generada automáticamente desde el navegador a bdd mysql php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Quiero darle click a un boton y abrir un formulario automaticamente este formulario tenga la fecha generada automaticamente por el navegador, una vez ingresado los datos en el formulario enviar los datos con la fecha a sus respectivos campos.

```
                      <script type="text/javascript">
                          var miFechaActual = new Date();
                          var dia = miFechaActual.getDate()
                          var mes = parseInt(miFechaActual.getMonth()) + 1
                          var ano = miFechaActual.getFullYear()
                            document.write (dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano)
                      </script>
```

Con esto la salida de la fecha tengo 
Fecha Orden:28/11/2017 pero no se como enviarlo mediante php a bdd.

Comment: No has preguntado ningún problema de programación específico. Lo que buscas es "Cómo insertar datos a una base de datos desde php". En google tienes la solución.

Comment: El problema es que al ser una variable unica(si no 3 dia mes ano) no se como enviarlo en la consulta en un solo insert ?

Comment: O si existiría otra forma de hacerlo directamente con php

Comment: Crea una variable entonces, concatena las variables dia, mes y ano. `var fechaCompleta = dia.concat(mes, ano);` y si quieres con las barras: `var fechaCompleta = dia.concat("/", mes, "/", ano);`

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes,
Tienes dos opciones, insertar los valores a la base de datos recargando la pagina, o mediante Ajax. Si usar Jquery, la función Jquery.ajax es muy simple de usar.
Por ejemplo crear esta función:

```
function insertBD(fecha){
        var parametros = {
                "fecha" : fecha
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   'ajax.php',
                type:  'post',
                success:  function (response) {
                        alert('fecha insertada correctamente');
                }
        });
}
```

Luego en tu código haces la llamada:

```
var miFechaActual = new Date();
var dia = miFechaActual.getDate()
var mes = parseInt(miFechaActual.getMonth()) + 1
var ano = miFechaActual.getFullYear()
insertBD(dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano)
```

El archivo ajax.php será el encargado de insertar a la base de datos y devolver una respuesta que se mostrará en el Alert.
Saludos

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta, justamente utilizo ajax para procesar enviar la respuesta al servidor pero, no se como tomar la variable fecha que creo mediante ese script o si seria mas facil en tal caso utilizar php disculpa soy muy novato en el tema postee mi codigo sin estilos y demas funciones php en codepen.io
https://codepen.io/JuanJose/project/editor/XGRknn
En teoria es lo que quiero una vez al cargar el fomulario se cargue la fecha actual y luego con los datos ingresados desde teclado enviarlo con la fecha y id tal vez me explico mejor ? muchas gracias